# Can't publish Android Library when it stand alone

Tags: android, android-library, jitpack

- Where: Build file '/home/jitpack/build/build.gradle' line: 53
- What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'build'.

  > Could not find method implementation() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Above  is the log when i try to upload a library to jitpack ( which does not have any app sample, only apply plugin: 'com.android.library'). I was uploaded at least 3 project with sample app inside it and it work perfect but this one not. I dont really know what i facing so any one please show me some solutions.

I am posting full log here.

> https://jitpack.io/com/github/cuong292/gemcore/-757446dc0a-1/build.log

Below is my app level build gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable false
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    api "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"
    api "com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0"
    api "com.android.support:design:28.0.0"
    api "com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0"

    compile "com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.1"

    annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.1"

    api "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.0"
    api "com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1"
    api "org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1"

    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.8.1'
    api 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    api 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
}

// build a jar with source files
task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}

task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    failOnError false
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.sourceFiles
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    classpath += configurations.implementation
}

// build a jar with javadoc
task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
    archives javadocJar
}
```

Comment: post your build.gradle files

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti i added,please review it pls.thanks

Comment: which version of gradle plugin are you using?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti i use the newest one, the 5.4.1 version

Comment: I suppose 5.4.1 is the gradle version. Are you using the classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti i must emphasize that i put the library stand alone and i added the gradle folder into it

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti i think it must inside project:build.gradle.but this one is not contain it cause apply plugin: 'com.android.library'.Am i right or i must create a new one????.And i cant find classPath anyway

Answer (score 0):

Finally,after hours of work and base on @GabrieleMariotti(thanks u so much) suggest,i find out that my stand alone library need a specify buildtool.And just add buildscript and allprojects (which normaly inside your build.gradle project level) to make it work.And remember to remove all task{}

Comment: Hi @shadow , can you please post your solution, I dont really understand your answer